# How to search a database in VB2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I'm using Visual basic 2010, I've created 3 text boxes with which i want the user to enter an ID number into the id number and all others will populate the first and last name associated with the ID. I also want the datagridview to hone in on the row with the corresponding first and last name and ID number. I appreciate all your help, thanks!

I populated my database with this:

```
    Last_NameTextBox.Text = strLastName.ToString
    First_NameTextBox.Text = strStudent.ToString
    IDTextBox.Text = strIdNumber.ToString

    DataGridViewStudents.DataSource = MyDataRow.Table()
    DataGridViewStudents.Rows.Add(MyDataRow)

    'Search id
    Dim findId() As Data.DataRow
    findId = MyDataRow.GetChildRows(txtId.Text)
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: To elaborate on the above comment: It's on your first line